# Logo not responsive

Tags: android, css, responsive-design

I have a problem with the responsiveness of my logo. The mobile/tablet dropdown menu starts from with 1000px but for some reason the logo doesn't stay centered on some sizes like landscape galaxy S3. I have made a screen of two sizes of the screen: http://s7.postimg.org/5hqfg0rq3/logo_not_centered.jpg

I gave the logo element margin:0 auto.

Does anyone have a clue why it doesnt stay centered? Thanks in advance your help is geatly appreciated

The website adres is [[1](http://www.elephantdesign.nl)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the image on the same div that the triangles.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to let the html center elements horizontally without using position absolute and left:50%. 
to fix that issue:

```
.logo_wrapper{
    remove the left:50%;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
.q_logo{
    remove left:0;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
}
.q_logo a{
    remove left:50%
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but I still can't get it to work using your css.. should i also remove the position properties?

Comment: I believe so... sorry, I played with it and forgot to add that.

Comment: I don't think that works it still makes jumps from center to the right on certain screen sizes :(